# Multiple data points at same datetime highcharts

Tags: highcharts

I am using line chart to plot the graph.
I have multiple data point at same datetime like below.

```
[[Date.UTC(2015,05,25,03,29), 560], [Date.UTC(2015,05,25,03,29), 548],
[Date.UTC(2015,05,25,03,29), 628], [Date.UTC(2015,05,25,03,29), 740], 
[Date.UTC(2015,05,25,03,29), 380], [Date.UTC(2015,05,25,03,29), 548], 
[Date.UTC(2015,05,25,03,29), 628], [Date.UTC(2015,05,25,03,29), 740], 
[Date.UTC(2015,05,25,03,29), 380], [Date.UTC(2015,05,25,03,29), 548], 
[Date.UTC(2015,05,25,03,29), 628], [Date.UTC(2015,05,25,03,29), 740], 
[Date.UTC(2015,05,25,03,29), 380], [Date.UTC(2015,05,25,03,29), 548], 
[Date.UTC(2015,05,25,03,29), 628], [Date.UTC(2015,05,25,03,29), 740], 
[Date.UTC(2015,05,25,03,29), 7740], [Date.UTC(2015,05,25,03,29), 548], 
[Date.UTC(2015,05,25,03,29), 628], [Date.UTC(2015,05,25,03,29), 740], 
[[Date.UTC(2015,05,25,03,29), 380], [Date.UTC(2015,05,25,19,46), 204], 
[Date.UTC(2015,05,25,19,46), -248], [Date.UTC(2015,05,25,19,46), 220], 
[Date.UTC(2015,05,25,19,46), -192], [Date.UTC(2015,05,25,19,46), -696], 
[Date.UTC(2015,05,25,19,46), -132], [Date.UTC(2015,05,25,19,46), -76],
[Date.UTC(2015,05,25,19,48), 2688], [Date.UTC(2015,05,25,19,49), 1668],
[Date.UTC(2015,05,25,19,49), 788], [Date.UTC(2015,05,25,19,49), 584],
[Date.UTC(2015,05,25,19,49), 100]]
```

If I plotting above values, i can see only latest values.

```
for [Date.UTC(2015,05,25,03,29) : 380
for [Date.UTC(2015,05,25,19,46) : -76
for [Date.UTC(2015,05,25,19,49) :100
```

Also If i download the graph values in excel, it has only above values.

How can i see all the data points at same time in graph also in excel sheet?

Comment: Reported in our bugtracker [here](https://github.com/highslide-software/export-csv/issues/49)

Comment: Is this issue resolved?

Comment: Not yet, if will be fixed, then ticket have "closed" status.